# Use css page and print setting for html doc wider than one page

Tags: css, printing

I have some interactive tables on same html doc. Input by the client generates these tables using javascript on the client side.

I want to use the browser print menu to save as pdf or print each table, one at a time.

Most can be printed in Portrait without changing the browser print setting.

However there is one table that require landscape. At 100% scale, it is more than 1.5 A4 size.

I do not wish to shrink (will be too tiny to read). So I want to print out as 2 page document.

None of the browsers will give me this.

On Google Chrome, the landscape setting gives blank page. Only the Portrait will show table but wont print second page.

On Edge and Mozilla, the Landscape setting shows the table but print only the first page.

I have used `print` for all pages. I have scrolled to the 2nd page. No luck.

Here is my css file:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    padding: auto;
    margin: auto;
    overflow:scroll;
    style='overflow-x:auto;'
}

.page {
    display: display;
    width: 21cm;
    min-height: 29.7cm;
    padding: 0cm;
    margin: 1cm;
}

@media print {
    .page {
        margin: 1cm;
        min-height: initial;
    }
}
```

Is there any uncomplicated solution to this?

Comment: I suppose that `style='overflow-x:auto;'` in `body{}` shouldn't be there.

Comment: Even when I removed style overflow, I get same result. So i am still confronted with same problem